# python winsound.PlaySound SND_ASYNC is not working

Tags: python, windows, winsound

it is not working because of the flag, which is winsound.SND_ASYNC, but there aren't any error messages.

```
import winsound


winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/alarm.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_LOOP | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

However, blow code is working... it played the sound of "alarm.wav"

```
import winsound


winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/alarm.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

I don't know why it is...